# What are x , y axis values when not specified for kmeans scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

This code : runs k-means algorithm from scikit-learn package :

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

X = np.array([[10, 2 , 9], [1, 4 , 3], [1, 0 , 3],
               [4, 2 , 1], [4, 4 , 7], [4, 0 , 5], [4, 6 , 3],[4, 1 , 7],[5, 2 , 3],[6, 3 , 3],[7, 4 , 13]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(X)

k = 3
kmeans.fit(X)

labels = kmeans.labels_
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

for i in range(k):
    # select only data observations with cluster label == i
    ds = X[np.where(labels==i)]
    # plot the data observations
    pyplot.plot(ds[:,0],ds[:,1],'o')
    # plot the centroids
    lines = pyplot.plot(centroids[i,0],centroids[i,1],'kx')
    # make the centroid x's bigger
    pyplot.setp(lines,ms=15.0)
    pyplot.setp(lines,mew=2.0)
pyplot.show()
```

generates :

[image]

As I've not set the x and y axis labels what do these axis values represent ?

scikit-learn utilizes the Euclidian distance measure for computing the distance between each point, so are the axis values representative of the Euclidean distances ?

The doc http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html does not describe this scenario.

Update : it does appear to be just plotting first two two dimension in array as using

```
X = np.array([[10, 2 , 90], [1, 4 , 35], [1, 0 , 30],
               [4, 2 , 1], [4, 4 , 7], [4, 0 , 5], [4, 6 , 3],[4, 1 , 7],[5, 2 , 3],[6, 3 , 3],[7, 4 , 13]])
```

I've updated the 3'rd dimensions for first 3 parameters to : to 90 , 35 & 40 . This does not have any impact on resultant plot. So in order to visualize dimensions > 2 I should run a PCA analysis on the data.

Comment: Your X has three co-ordinates. I would assume those are x1, x2 and y... Then the axes on your plot are probably x1 on horizontal and x2 on vertical, no? ... We actually see those points on the graph. Look at (10, 2), and (4, 1)...

Comment: The line that plots the data is quite clear to me: `pyplot.plot(ds[:,0],ds[:,1], 'o')`. It actually does plot first vs second column of your data (`ds` is a subset of `X`), which means, it does not do any magic, it is just plotting the first 2 dimensions of your data `X`. I don't see where the confusion comes from, unless you have not written that piece of code. Also, you run `kmeans.fit(X)` twice, which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo the confusion for me is that I'm unsure how scikit-learn k-means classifies dimensions of size > 2. It appears it ignores the dimensions > 2 , at least when plotting as you point out  : pyplot.plot(ds[:,0],ds[:,1], 'o') . Perhaps k-means it does not makes sense to attempt to visualize k-means for datasets with dimensions > 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

I think it's simply plotting your first variable on the "x", and your second variable on the "y".

(But "x" and "y" are the wrong terms.)

**Detail**

In machine learning, the terms x and y are usually used a bit differently. In your case your X matrix contains data points with 3 values:

- The first two values are usually called x1 and x2 variables (x with 1 subscript, if I could format it that way).
- And the third value is ... I'm not sure yet. I don't see it on the plot.

If you look at your original data in X, you see [10, 2, 9], [1, 4, 3], ...

The first two variables of the first data point are (10, 2).

- You can see a point plotted at horizontal 10, vertical 2.
- There is a second point plotted at horizontal 1, vertical 4.
- And so on ...

So from that you can basically see that the horizontal axis is x1, and the vertical is x2.

I don't know how the third value appears on the plot. It's possible that it's the color, but usually in k-means, the color is used to separate the different values into clusters. So each color is a cluster.

So I don't really see where the third value is. But that wasn't your question! :)

You probably want the documentation for pyplot, not for scikit-learn. Here is pyplot: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html